# How to upload photos to Huawei OBS Bucket?

Tags: angular, cloud, huawei-cloud

Hello I have my secret key, access key, bucket name, bucket url, all the data, I just dont know how to put it all together to starting uploading to Huawei OBS, Im using Angular, please help.

I found these resources:
https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/api-obs/obs_04_0017.html
https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/api-obs/obs_04_0007.html